# Oracle 12c Cloning PDBs from disk

Tags: oracle, clone, rman

In Oracle 12c is it possible to clone/duplicate a PDB into a different CDB using a disk backup?

So if I take a backup to disk as follows, can I then clone from this backup into a new PDB in a different CDB?

```
RMAN> connect target "c##oradbmaint/temp1234 as sysbackup"

connected to target database: TEST44 (DBID=958109427)

RMAN> connect catalog rman/*****@RMANCATDB

connected to recovery catalog database

RMAN> backup pluggable database PDB001 to destination '/u01/app/oracle/backup';
```